# Find the context switch function of freertos

Tags: c, multithreading, real-time, stm32, freertos

I'm using freeRTOS CMSIS v1 in a STM32 with a cortex-M7 architecture. My goal in the moment is to study it and understand the "behind the curtain" mechanism (I'm using the debugger for this purpose).

I'm trying to reach the "context-switch" function, but I've not been able to get there. Is it possible to reach it? To see the source code?.

thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an exception handler routine (supervisior call handler):

```
void xPortPendSVHandler( void )
{
    /* This is a naked function. */

    __asm volatile
    (
    "   mrs r0, psp                         \n"
    "   isb                                 \n"
    "                                       \n"
    "   ldr r3, pxCurrentTCBConst           \n" /* Get the location of the current TCB. */
    "   ldr r2, [r3]                        \n"
    "                                       \n"
    "   tst r14, #0x10                      \n" /* Is the task using the FPU context?  If so, push high vfp registers. */
    "   it eq                               \n"
    "   vstmdbeq r0!, {s16-s31}             \n"
    "                                       \n"
    "   stmdb r0!, {r4-r11, r14}            \n" /* Save the core registers. */
    "   str r0, [r2]                        \n" /* Save the new top of stack into the first member of the TCB. */
    "                                       \n"
    "   stmdb sp!, {r0, r3}                 \n"
    "   mov r0, %0                          \n"
    "   msr basepri, r0                     \n"
    "   dsb                                 \n"
    "   isb                                 \n"
    "   bl vTaskSwitchContext               \n"
    "   mov r0, #0                          \n"
    "   msr basepri, r0                     \n"
    "   ldmia sp!, {r0, r3}                 \n"
    "                                       \n"
    "   ldr r1, [r3]                        \n" /* The first item in pxCurrentTCB is the task top of stack. */
    "   ldr r0, [r1]                        \n"
    "                                       \n"
    "   ldmia r0!, {r4-r11, r14}            \n" /* Pop the core registers. */
    "                                       \n"
    "   tst r14, #0x10                      \n" /* Is the task using the FPU context?  If so, pop the high vfp registers too. */
    "   it eq                               \n"
    "   vldmiaeq r0!, {s16-s31}             \n"
    "                                       \n"
    "   msr psp, r0                         \n"
    "   isb                                 \n"
    "                                       \n"
    #ifdef WORKAROUND_PMU_CM001 /* XMC4000 specific errata workaround. */
        #if WORKAROUND_PMU_CM001 == 1
    "           push { r14 }                \n"
    "           pop { pc }                  \n"
        #endif
    #endif
    "                                       \n"
    "   bx r14                              \n"
    "                                       \n"
    "   .align 4                            \n"
    "pxCurrentTCBConst: .word pxCurrentTCB  \n"
    ::"i"(configMAX_SYSCALL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY)
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much friend!! Real life saver.